# Make a cable go into a water container without any leaks

Tags: cables, waterproof, underwater

This might not be the best place to post this, so if I'm in the wrong, please let me know.

I have a water container that I want to put a temperature probe into, but I can't drill a hole from the top because of other hardware. I need it coming from the side.

Is there any way of making the cable come in and out of the container without making it leak?

I'm trying to avoid hot glue to seal the hole. Bonus point if the solution allows to remove the cable for maintenance.

Comment: If your wall surface is curved, your choices are limited on connectors.  Bulkhead connectors need two O-rings.

Comment: Another task is sealing of sensor to cable joint. May be it is better to use threaded temperature probe? They come with plenty various lengths, sizes and types.

Comment: A waterproof fitting to pass a cable through a wall is often called a 'Cable Gland"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the surface of the container is flat or has a fairly large radius you could use a cable gland; these can be waterproof to a significant pressure.  https://nz.rs-online.com/web/p/cable-glands/2647336

Answer (score 0):

Yes, used bulhead connectors for this.

Various designs available.

Or used pipe joints - or pipe butt connectors - can be had with one side extended.

Bigger stores carry them. Won’t say where I would go as you likely have different stores…